# Concatenation of two different strings from a different file included in the shell script

Tags: unix

I have a shell script, where I have included a file which contains variables with some assigned values.

When I execute the shell script to concatenate the variables from the included file, it is behaving weird.

Here when the variables are echoed separated, they provide expected value. 
But when I concatenate the two variables, the second variable is overwriting the first one.

**Config File - conf.cfg**

```
var1=xxxxxxxx
var2=yyyyyy
```

**Show Script - Show.sh**

```
source ./conf.cnf

echo $var1
echo $var2
echo $var1$var2
```

**Expected Result**

```
xxxxxxxx
yyyyyy
xxxxxxxxyyyyyy
```

**Actual Result**

```
xxxxxxxx
yyyyyy
yyyyyyxx
```

Comment: `conf.cfg` is in DOS format (carriage returns at the end of each line). There's probably a duplicate question around somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. My file is using .cnf or .cfg which were in DOS not being included properly in the the shell script. So I changed it to .txt and included in the shell script. It was working fine.

Comment: That seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

It just got resolved after I changed the extension of the conf file from .cfg to .txt